# Hibernate EmptyInterceptor change query type

Tags: java, hibernate

When I update an entity, I want to update a modification_tms field automatically.

For this, I use an EmptyInterceptor and the method:

```
 public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {}
```

and I have what I expect.

Now, when I delete an entity, I want to update a deletion_tms field automatically and I want an update query, not a delete query.

I try to do that with the method:

```
 public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {...}
```

I can set a new value into the field deletion_tms, but of course, the entity is deleted after. I don't know if there is a way to "transform" the delete query into an update query.

Can you help me ?

I'm using hibernate 4

Thansk in advance.

Comment: Do you have a DAO layer in you application? Just implement the delete method to call `update` on hibernate session.

Comment: I have a DAO layer but this solution doesn't work for me. If I have an entity  (named A) with a list of other entities (named B) I don't call a delete method when I remove B --> A.remove(b)

Comment: You mean that B contains an A inside and when you remove B, it will only effect to B, and A which was inside B will stay. Is it?

Comment: No,  sorry. A contains B. And when I do A.remove(B) I see the query "delete from B....." In this case, I don't use a delete method into the DAO layer. For this reason, I want to use an interceptor (or something like that) to update the field deletion_tms and transform a delete into an update